# Change Script tag value dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamcially change the script tag value based on user choice from drop down, find my code below, it does not return anything

```
function dynamic()
{
        var sel_size = jQuery("#block_size").val(); 
        var st = sel_size.split("x");
        var site_url = '<?php echo $site_url;?>';
        var path = '<?php echo $this->config->item("path");?>';
        var id = '<?php echo $zone_id;?>';
        var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src = url+path+"?id="+id+"width="+st[0]+"height="+st[1];
            s.innerHTML = null;
            alert(s);
}
```

What is wrong in this, please correct my code, Any help Appreciated...

Comment: where did you define `url`? in `url+path`

Comment: _it will not return anything_ -- yes because return statement is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply script you have to run it:

```
function dynamic()
{
    // ... all other stuff
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = url + path + "?id=" + id + "width=" + st[0] + "height=" + st[1];
    // Run your script
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is `appendChild?`

you have created dynamic script tag but you failed to append on body...

append it into body.

document.body.appendChild(s);

Answer (score 0):

In your function not having **url** variable. only having **site_url** variable.So try this one.And you are not put any return value on that function.

```
function dynamic()
{
    var sel_size = jQuery("#block_size").val(); 
    var st = sel_size.split("x");
    var site_url = '<?php echo $site_url;?>';
    var path = '<?php echo $this->config->item("path");?>';
    var id = '<?php echo $zone_id;?>';
    var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = site_url+path+"?id="+id+"width="+st[0]+"height="+st[1];
        s.innerHTML = null;
        alert(s);
    return something;    // what you need to return in that one.
}
```

In this code may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If **url** variable not present and have only **site_url** then use following code. Also added **'&'** to src.

```
 function dynamic(){
    var sel_size = jQuery("#block_size").val(); 
    var st = sel_size.split("x");
    var site_url = '<?php echo $site_url;?>';
    var path = '<?php echo $this->config->item("path");?>';
    var id = '<?php echo $zone_id;?>';
    var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = site_url+path+"?id="+id+"&width="+st[0]+"&height="+st[1];
        s.innerHTML = null;
        alert(s);}
```